# Is there a Micronaut analogue for Spring @RequestScope?

Tags: java, micronaut

Is there a `@RequestScope` analogue in Micronaut?
 If there are no equivalent annotations, how I can achieve the same effect in Micronaut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been added since version 1.2.0.RC1

You can find documentation [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/api/io/micronaut/runtime/http/scope/RequestScope.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Spring expert, but from what I understand there is nothing like @RequestScope in Micronaut.
However, u can set request scoped data using attributes on the current request via `ServerRequestContext.currentRequest()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1461), the feature is planned

Comment: cool thx, Ivan. maybe you know the issue to track when the feature will be added?

Comment: @TarasK
No, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

What do you need from the request scope in your context? If you need to access something like current `HttpRequest`, try to use `@ThreadLocal`-Scope. https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/runtime/context/scope/ThreadLocal.html . First, you need of course somehow to put current `HttpRequest` into your `ThreadLocal`. Depending on your web framework it can be done with i.e. interceptors.